# Check user login with LinkButton or Hyperlink performance

Tags: c#, asp.net

Which option is better, when you have redirect to other page and user need to be logged in to use it.

1. With **linkbutton** you can in onClick event check if user is logged in and then redirect...
2. With **hyperlink** you can set navigateUrl and than on other page on page load check if user is logged in, if not redirect to login page...

Which option is better for performance or the right one to use it... In first option you have postback (whole page reload) in second you have only redirects but also load the page_load event if user is not logged in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Hyperlink` control takes the user directly to the specified location
without posting back to the server.

The `LinkButton` control first posts the form to the server, then navigates to the URL. If you need to do any server-side processing before going to the target URL, use a `LinkButton`.

if there is no server-side processing necessary, don't waste a round trip and use the `HyperLink` control.

So,from your question: `Which option is better, when you have redirect to other page and user need to be logged in to use it` , seems you want that when user is logged in, then only they should be able to use the page they are redircted to.

So, In case the new page where they are redirected to, Validates the user also, then Go for `Hyperlink`. In case, the newly redirected page doesn't validates the user, and you require validated user to use the new page, go for `LinkButton`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to this question lies in the application of the control.

Use a link button when you are working within the page (postbacks), use a hyperlink when you are redirecting the browser.

Ideally the hyperlink would be used in this case as lets assume they are logged in, once you get to the page if their not send them to the login page. Once they login send them back to the page they requested.

Now you may also think about checking if their logged in before even displaying the hyperlink or any other control.

Cheers.